# Drive V3 API : java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

This is how I create  "AbstractInputStreamContent" from inputstream of file:

```
final Long length = Long.valueOf(filesData.get(uploadedFileName).get("size")).longValue();
    final InputStream fileStream = item.openStream(); //FileItemStream item
    AbstractInputStreamContent fileContent = new AbstractInputStreamContent(uploadedFileMimeType) {
        @Override
        public boolean retrySupported() {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public long getLength() throws IOException {
            return length;
        }
        @Override
        public InputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
            return fileStream;
        }
    };
```

And "InputStreamContent" as:

```
InputStreamContent fileContent = new InputStreamContent(uploadedFileMimeType, item.openStream());
fileContent.setLength(Long.valueOf(filesData.get(uploadedFileName).get("size")).longValue());
```

To replace old file with new file I use(both files are of .docx format):

```
Drive.Files.Update update = driveService.files().update(fileIdOfFileToReplace,fileMeta,fileContent);
        update.set("uploadType", "resumable");
        update.getMediaHttpUploader().setDirectUploadEnabled(false);
        update.getMediaHttpUploader().setChunkSize(MediaHttpUploader.DEFAULT_CHUNK_SIZE);
        File updatedFile = update.execute();
```

Uploading a new file works fine whether I use InputStreamContent or AbstractInputStreamContent. **But update gives "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException" with both**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:111)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:37)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.media.MediaHttpUploader.setInitiationRequestMethod(MediaHttpUploader.java:872)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.initializeMediaUpload(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:237)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files$Update.<init>(Drive.java:3163)
    at com.google.api.services.drive.Drive$Files.update(Drive.java:3113)
    at com.util.DocumentsUtil.updateFile(DocumentsUtil.java:22)
    at com.controllers.collab.documents.Documents.fileUpload(Documents.java:165)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:44)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by giving exclusion of google-api-client from each google api maven dependency. Later added google-api-client-1.22.0-SNAPSHOT dependency from sonatype repo. It works fine